# Is it possible to move multiple tabs to a new window in Opera?

Tags: browser, opera

Is it possible to select multiple tabs from one window in Opera and then move them to another/new window in one go - that is, without moving each tab individually? I'm not bothered if the functionality comes out of the box or via an extension.

I'm currently using 32.0.1948.69 on OS X El Capitan and have tried various combinations of <kbd>cmd</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, and <kbd>shift</kbd> while clicking multiple tabs. None seem to work.

**EDIT**: added clarification that I'm not interested in moving multiple tabs one at a time

Comment: I'm missing the same feature. I would call it "Detach tabs to the right" and place it in the tab context menu. Unfortunately, I also didn't find a plugin which helps out here.

Comment: yes, I was hoping for the same ... I prefer Opera to Chrome for its lighter resource footprint, and in so many ways it's functionally equivalent; but multiple tab select is a very handy thing I'm missing greatly from Chrome

Comment: I don't understand the "clarification" that you're "not interested in moving multiple tabs at one time" ... I thought that was the whole question?

Comment: The only answer to the question is about moving one tab at a time (click and drag one tab to a new window, repeat for each tab). I was already aware of that ability, hence I added the clarification that I want to select `n` tabs at once and move them all to a new/different window in one go.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old thread, but I would like to share my way of doing it, for help in future:

- Select first tab of the group
- Ctrl + Shift and click last tab of the group
- Right click and choose "Save tabs as Speed Dial Folder"
- Goto Speed dial
- Right click on saved folder
- select "Open all in new window"

Comment: Great answer! Thanks! Very useful, it even could be guessed by intuition, but not all, like me, i believe did manage to find and use it!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can move more Opera tabs in one time, but you can drag 1 tab out of the window that you use to create a new window, and than you can move the tabs **one by one**.

To do that you can drag&drop the other tabs from the first window to the button to create a new tab in the second window.

This is the way i can do that in Windows i hope it work in OS X.

Comment: Yeah ... not nearly as handy as being able to move a whole group at once.  It becomes a whole delicate operation having to drag them one by one.  Thanks anyhow though.